# Desktop PC won't start Win10 after blue screen error

Tags: windows-10, desktop-computer

After a blue screen error, my Windows 10 PC won't start. My monitor and power supply have power. The main power switch and emergency restart switch make no difference. I can't exactly remember the name of blue screen error as the screen was hazy. How can I restart it again?

Comment: Try booting from USB, either in WinPE or Linux.

Comment: There is no display showing on my monitor screen. So how can I boot my pc?

Comment: Please get the PC model # from the serial # sticker (we don't need the serial #, just the model #) &the make of the PC; click [edit] to add that in  your question. Are you OK opening the desktop PC case? ... If so, unplug the power cord from the back of the PC, after 5 minutes, open the case and position it so you can see the motherboard... Make sure the power supply switch on the back of the PC case is set to **1** and not **0**, then plug in the power cord. You may see a brief glow, or an LED come on. Turn on the front panel power switch; any changes of LEDs on the motherboard?

Comment: I have opened the pc cage and reset some connections. The problem is solved. Maybe there was a problem with connections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The BSOD was probably caused by a hardware error or power surge, which might have
caused some damage to the computer or the monitor.

Check all connectors and reseat the display adapter (if not soldiered to the
motherboard), although the chances are slim that this would help.

If you cannot find anything, try with another monitor, to see if the problem
is there. If you still cannot find anything, the computer needs a repairman.